# Apache Reverse Proxy with Localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

```
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8080/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:8080/bar
```

Is localhost with respect to the client or the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost is in respect of the server or rather the machine which is asking the question. When a system does a name service lookup for localhost it will (most likely) get 127.0.0.1 or ::1 back as the address. This is the address of the loopback interface on the local machine.

Comment: so, what machine is "asking" the question in this case.  The client is requesting a url through http, but the reverse proxy is on the server...

Comment: The server is asking the question - it has to translate your proxy directives into addresses so it can hand the client off to that address:port